# What's the most elegant way to have server side hook points for insert/update/delete "events"

Tags: meteor

I'm looking for a way to have server side only hook points for updates/deletes and inserts in a named mongo collection.
I understand that the publish machinery has a way to inform clients  about server side operations, but that's not what I want. The idea is to organize server side "side-effect processing" and server side validation on the typical collection life cycle events.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should have a look at collection-hooks : https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

Comment: Cool, didn't know that one yet. I'm using already autoForm which uses Collection2, but as far as I can see they don't support real server side hook points (only validation points). I think collection-hooks is a good fit. Thanks.

Comment: The `collection-hooks` package is nice for having more control, but you might be able to solve your problem just by using Meteor's [cursor.observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe) functionality, which works both server-side and client-side. In fact, this is the underlying mechanism behind Meteor's publications.

Comment: @sbking : Thanks but not sure how to use observe here. Let's stick to a very simple use case. I want to add a CreationDate field automatically when a customer is inserted in the mongodb customers collection. How to use observe here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are other solutions, but I find matb33's meteor-collection-hooks was pretty self-explanatory and easy to use.

Once I added it to my meteor project, I can create a new file like mycollection_hooks.js file in my SERVER folders (`server` is important because if you put them in the lib or shared folder, they will run twice: once on the client, and once on the server)

In the new file I can just do

```
MyCollection.before.insert((userId, doc) => {
    doc.createdAt = new Date(); // will add a createdAt field to the document
});

MyCollection.after.insert((userId, doc) => {
    // do some stuff after the document is inserted
});
```

In addition, there are methods for before/after for inserts, finds, updates, and deletes.

just run `meteor add matb33:collection-hooks`

here are the docs: [matb33/meteor-collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks)

Comment: Although I don't think this completely answers the question, this sure is interesting for meteor users.

Comment: Oh! I assumed the asker was using meteor because he tagged meteor in the question....

But then I realized that the question was asked a little over 4 years ago, so I doubt he'll be back to check anyway ^.^.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice the meteor tag.